# Reference to generic type index Requires Arguments - Algolia Search, Swift 3

Tags: swift3, xcode8, algolia

The following code gives an error. 
The error occurs on "var businessIndes: Index!"
It keeps asking me to add < Any>! then once I do it tells me to remove < Any>!
What's weird is that this is supposed to be a term used by Algolia search, so I do not see what would be causing this. Any help would be appreciated. It's probably something small and obvious but I cannot seem to figure it out.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Firebase
import AlgoliaSearch
import SwiftyJSON
import AFNetworking

class ExploreVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource,UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchControllerDelegate {


let client = Client(appID: "APP-ID", apiKey: "API-KEY")

override func viewDidLoad() {

}


@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var searchController: UISearchController!

var businessSearch = [Business]()

var businessIndex: Index!
let query = Query()
var searchId = 0
var displayedSearchId = -1
var loadedPage: UInt = 0
var nbPages: UInt = 0
```

Comment: Appears this error is caused by SwiftyJSON. Is there an alternative that I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, specify which pod you would like to use.

e.g.

***AlgoliaSearch.Index!***